# IDW with QGIS from a vector points file within a mask

Tags: qgis, raster, masking, inverse-distance-weighted

Given two inputs:

- A shapefile: points
- A raster: mask

I want to interpolate the points within the extent of the raster except the NoData pixels that i want to use as a mask. NoData pixels are the sea and i want my IDW only for the land.

This would be easy in ArcGIS but i would like to it with QGIS to make easy to use for anyone.

I came with the idea to use r.mask but it turned out to be not available in QGIS...

Any idea about what would be the process to make it possible later in graphic modeler ?

Comment: You can access IDW module of SAGA GIS via Processing to create interpolation and then apply mask to the result.

Comment: Well sounds to work pretty well. How can i tagged this question solved ? Thanks a lot SS_Rebelious

Answer (score 1):

You can access IDW module of SAGA GIS via Processing to create interpolation and then apply mask to the result.